# prove Lindenbaum’s lemma for a countable language

Tags: logic, model-theory

Been reading through some model theory and got to a section on constructing models from
syntax and i have been presented with the following problem, sorry for the lack of solution i just have no idea where to even begin, any help would be appreciated!! Really want to get my head around model theory.

**Lindenbaum’s Lemma** If Σ is a finitely satisfiable set of Lsentences
then there is a finitely satisfiable, deductively closed and complete
set Σ* of L-sentences such that Σ ⊆ Σ*

**Problem**

Let L be a countable language, and enumerate the set of L-sentences
as (ϕn)n∈N. Let Σ be a finitely satisfiable set of L-sentences, and show
that at least one of Σ ∪ {ϕ0} or Σ ∪ {¬ϕ0} is finitely satisfiable. Then
build on this idea to prove Lindenbaum’s lemma in the case that L is
countable.

Comment: You can find a proof of it in any math.log textbook; see e.g. Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA42) (5th ed - 2013), page 42.

Comment: Does it follow the same method outlined in the problem? sorry i wasnt able to view page 42

Comment: The proof suggested in the problem is essentially the second proof [here](http://planetmath.org/lindenbaumslemma).